# Como setar atributo do HTML com @yield() no Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, template, atributos

Eu estou tentando criar um `template` para meu painel de controle em Laravel.

Quero que no canto superior direito tenha um botão de VOLTAR, onde posso setar o link com o `@yield`

Eu tentei fazer o seguinte código, porém não tive sucesso, ele mostra como se o `href` estivesse em branco

```
// layouts.master.blade.php
<a href="@yield('voltar')">Voltar</a>
```

e na página estendida

```
// usuario.editar.php
@extends('../layouts.master')

@section('voltar')
    dashboard
@stop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumindo que `dashboard` é o nome de sua route, você precisa converter para uma url válida antes de retornar para o `href`.

Tente o seguinte:

```
@extends('../layouts.master')

@section('voltar')
    link_to_route('dashboard')
@stop
```

Mais informações na [documentação do laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#views)